# How to add SectionList 's sections in React Native from an array

Tags: typescript, react-native, lodash, react-native-sectionlist

I have an array of objects called movies (`const movies = movie[]`). A movie has the following properties:

```
  movie: {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    date: Date;
    duration: number
  }
```

I want to use a RN `SectionList` component, making sections from the `movie.date` (Day):

```
**20 june 2020:**

Movie name | description | duration

Movie name | description | duration

**18 april 2020:**

Movie name | description | duration

Movie name | description | duration

...
```

How do I make the section and also how do I group my movies' array by date? I'm using lodash, but doing `const groupedMovies = groupBy(movies, movie => movie.date);` returns a collection and not an array.

ref.: https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to convert the data from the format

```
{
   "18 april 2020": [{...}, {...}, {...}],
   ...
}
```

into the format

```
[
   { "title": "18 April 2020", "data": [{...}, {...}, {...}] },
   ...
]
```

you can do this conversion as follows

```
const groupedMovies = groupBy(movies, movie => movie.date);
let data = Object.entries(groupedMovies).map(([key, value]) => ({ title: key, data: value }))
```

or with lodash's map

```
const groupedMovies = groupBy(movies, movie => movie.date);
let data = map(groupedMovies, (value, key) => ({ title: key, data: value }))
```